# System error when pinging another network's name

Tags: networking, dhcp, ping

Before I upgraded to Ubuntu 17.04, the following allowed me to ping another computer connected to the same network:

- `sudo apt install winbind libnss-winbind`
- Modify a line in `/etc/nsswitch.conf` to `hosts: files mdns4_minimal wins dns`

After applying the above changes in Ubuntu 16.04, I could ping my Windows 7 laptop by its name alone:

```
charlie@server ~ $ ping charlie-pc
PING charlie-pc (192.168.0.210) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from charlie-pc (192.168.0.210): icmp_seq=1 ttl=128 time=2.13 ms
```

Now when I do the same in Ubuntu 17.04, I get the following error:

```
charlie@server ~ $ ping charlie-pc
ping: charlie-pc: System error
```

I can still successfully ping my laptop by its IP address, however, I would like network names to be automatically resolved again...without adding them to `/etc/hosts`.

Comment: Problem corrected itself after package "windbind" was marked for upgrading, so I upgraded it.

Comment: I think I have the same problem, only I updated from 18.04 LTS to 20.04 LTS (Ubuntu-Server). Unfortunately nothing has been marked for upgrading. I actually uninstalled and reinstalled winbind and other related packages. So far nothing has helped. :-(

Comment: Try pinging windows-pc.local instead as I believe this is the designed way of accessing local computers (works in Debian Buster).

Answer (score 1):

The designed way of accessing local area network (LAN) computers requires **adding** `.local` to the name of the host.
Example:

```
ping charlie-pc.local
```

Thanks to the user @charlie for the idea.