# Error while running sudo apt update command

Tags: apt, 20.04, updates, sudo

```
$ sudo apt update
Err:1 https://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable InRelease
  System error resolving 'dl.google.com:https' - getaddrinfo (16: Device or resource busy)
Err:2 https://deb.nodesource.com/node_17.x focal InRelease
  System error resolving 'deb.nodesource.com:https' - getaddrinfo (16: Device or resource busy)
Err:3 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal InRelease
  System error resolving 'in.archive.ubuntu.com:http' - getaddrinfo (16: Device or resource busy)
Err:4 http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu focal InRelease
  System error resolving 'archive.canonical.com:http' - getaddrinfo (16: Device or resource busy)
Err:5 http://packages.microsoft.com/repos/code stable InRelease
  System error resolving 'packages.microsoft.com:http' - getaddrinfo (16: Device or resource busy)
Err:6 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security InRelease
  System error resolving 'in.archive.ubuntu.com:http' - getaddrinfo (16: Device or resource busy)
Err:7 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates InRelease
  System error resolving 'in.archive.ubuntu.com:http' - getaddrinfo (16: Device or resource busy)
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
All packages are up to date.
```

```
when i did the ping command, i got this error

$ ping in.archive.ubuntu.com
ping: in.archive.ubuntu.com: System error
```

```
$ ip a
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: enp2s0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 50:7b:9d:be:a1:6b brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.29.10/24 brd 192.168.29.255 scope global dynamic noprefixroute enp2s0
       valid_lft 3080sec preferred_lft 3080sec
    inet6 2405:201:f00e:fc33:ee4a:3b33:ee94:448/64 scope global temporary dynamic 
       valid_lft 3598sec preferred_lft 3598sec
    inet6 2405:201:f00e:fc33:545a:f3a:a9b3:399/64 scope global dynamic mngtmpaddr noprefixroute 
       valid_lft 3598sec preferred_lft 3598sec
    inet6 fe80::d88a:d74d:877e:a217/64 scope link noprefixroute 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
3: wlp3s0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether a8:a7:95:8b:47:7b brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.29.250/24 brd 192.168.29.255 scope global dynamic noprefixroute wlp3s0
       valid_lft 2985sec preferred_lft 2985sec
    inet6 2405:201:f00e:fc33:cbde:8518:cc78:7dc1/64 scope global temporary dynamic 
       valid_lft 3598sec preferred_lft 3598sec
    inet6 2405:201:f00e:fc33:bd35:f850:cace:fc3/64 scope global dynamic mngtmpaddr noprefixroute 
       valid_lft 3598sec preferred_lft 3598sec
    inet6 fe80::e4d4:1c01:e8ab:2d5d/64 scope link noprefixroute 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

```
$ ifconfig
enp2s0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.29.10  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.29.255
        inet6 2405:201:f00e:fc33:ee4a:3b33:ee94:448  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x0<global>
        inet6 2405:201:f00e:fc33:545a:f3a:a9b3:399  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x0<global>
        inet6 fe80::d88a:d74d:877e:a217  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 50:7b:9d:be:a1:6b  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 18251  bytes 17958928 (17.9 MB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 468  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 9382  bytes 1918435 (1.9 MB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
        inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
        loop  txqueuelen 1000  (Local Loopback)
        RX packets 5329  bytes 579810 (579.8 KB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 5329  bytes 579810 (579.8 KB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

wlp3s0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.29.250  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.29.255
        inet6 2405:201:f00e:fc33:cbde:8518:cc78:7dc1  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x0<global>
        inet6 fe80::e4d4:1c01:e8ab:2d5d  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        inet6 2405:201:f00e:fc33:bd35:f850:cace:fc3  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x0<global>
        ether a8:a7:95:8b:47:7b  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 678294  bytes 684218185 (684.2 MB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 24508  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 317517  bytes 73388064 (73.3 MB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

[image: error image]

Comment: Looks like your DNS is not working.

Comment: what does `ping in.archive.ubuntu.com` say if executed in your terminal? Put the answer into your question, **not** in a comment, so everyone sees it. Use the [edit](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1391177/edit) link

Comment: @kanehekili i have updated what you mentioned

Comment: I've never seen "System error" when using ping, but you can't have an internet connection. Can you add the output of `ip a` or `ifconfig` if the aforementioned doesn't work

Comment: @kanehekili i have added the outputs of "ip a " and "ifconfig"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your data it seems that your file `/etc/nsswitch.conf`might contain an invalid entry in the "hosts" line. Others have observed , that "wins" needs winbind to run [here](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=219427), a [similar problem](https://askubuntu.com/q/957552/906933) shows also how to check further.

So you would need to check your `nsswitch.conf` and your `resolv.conf` and consult the man pages (`man nsswitch.conf`) if those host entries are either valid or which additional services they might need.

[This article](https://serverfault.com/questions/814356/etc-resolv-conf-order-not-respected-by-ping) describes the difference between `ping` and `nslookup`: a ping rather checks if your "resolve" is working, while nslookup checks if your DNS is working

If you cannot find a solution, try to use `strace`as mentioned in the links above to get more infos about what is breaking

Comment: Thank you very much...

I have added "files mdns4_minimal [NOTFOUND=return] dns" in the "hosts" parameter in nsswitch.conf and i have successfully fixed my error.